# Is there any equivalent of "~" in cshml view file for TypeScript file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core

When we want to set URL to `src` parameter for tags like `img` in .cshtml view file, we can type `~/img/something.png` so the ASPNET Core MVC will expand the URL according to the settings. Now I want to do the same but in TypeScript. How can I do that?

P.S.: for moderators, I am sorry I'm confused when searching for this thing in the search bar, what should i type. If this same question is already been asked, please tell me where is it.

Answer (score 0):

try this [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDir) of typescript